# Twilio Java SDK 7.x in a Multi-Threaded environment:

Tags: twilio

The Twilio latest Java SDK 7.x uses Singleton method 'Twilio.init' for authorisation purpose, which is unsuitable for a multi-users web application.
Any idea to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

According to [this answer on the Twilio Java GitHub issues](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-java/issues/270#issuecomment-235012854) you can use the library without setting the account SID and auth token using `Twilio.init`. Instead, you can create your own `TwilioRestClient` object and execute the API calls using it.

For example:

```
import com.twilio.rest.http.TwilioRestClient;
import com.twilio.rest.resource.api.v2010.account.Call;

TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(accountSid, authToken);

Call call = Call.fetch('CAaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa').execute(client);
```

Let me know if that helps at all.